# Add transparent color overlay over an <img> tag

Tags: html, css

I want to add a transparent black overlay over an `img tag` with some text in it, like in the example screenshot below. Ideally only with `HTML` and `CSS`.

I have been searching for hours and can't find anything.

I know this could be easily done if the image is used as a background, but this isn't an option for us (SEO reasons).

[image: example overlay screenshot]

Comment: what code have you tried? Paste it in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That shouldn't be so bad.  Would something like this work?  First some HTML:

```css
 #container {
      position: relative;
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
    }

    #someimg {
      postion: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      clear: float;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
   <html>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <img id="someimg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg"</img>
          <div id="overlay">This is some text in an overlay</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks, on it!

Comment: thank you so much! you saved me from a mental breakdown

Comment: @JamesDanylik years later you saved another life! 

Answer (score 1):

[Mic.com](https://mic.com/) used the following code:

```
.article-card-8col__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.9));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.9));
}
```

I changed it slightly. You could also use their code with on a sibling div element of the image & the parent having `position: relative;` or use one like mine.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper:after{
  content: "";
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.9));
  background: linear-gradient(transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.9));
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="https://thumbs.mic.com/MTAxZmJlOGIyMSMvYzNOMU1wRTJjMEdyWUZySS1UVjNnMV9LVkZRPS8xMngyNzM6NDk4MHgyODA5LzgwMHg0NTAvZmlsdGVyczpmb3JtYXQoanBlZyk6cXVhbGl0eSg4MCkvaHR0cHM6Ly9zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3BvbGljeW1pYy1pbWFnZXMvanQwY2dmZXZ5aW10aGhqZzBtYXc4cHZxNndrZmdwbmNqNzQzeTB4YmhybWtyOGc0YXYxcHVidWVldzU0OWIwcC5qcGc.jpg" />
</div>
```